# On an existing notebook, how to transform all "double brackets" into "DoubleBracket"

Tags: front-end, notebooks, replacement, boxes

Sometimes, having all double brackets `[[...]]` transformed into `\\[LeftDoubleBracket] ... \\[RightDoubleBracket]` can really facilitate code reading.

On a given notebook, how to transform all occurrences automatically (on input cells)?

The other way around is easier, but a couple of buttons interface will get extra... thanks.

Comment: the lefts are easier :)

Comment: Cell>Convert To>StandardForm does this (it is what i use), but it also makes other changes that may not be desirable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Palette button**

```
CreatePalette[
 Button["Compact Part",
   Do[
     With[{
       celldata = NotebookRead[cell],
       pattern = RuleDelayed[
         RowBox[{h__, "[", RowBox[{"[", spec___, "]"}], "]"}],
         RowBox[{h, "\[LeftDoubleBracket]", RowBox[{spec}], 
            "\[RightDoubleBracket]"}]
       ]
     },
     If[
       Not @ FreeQ[celldata, First @ pattern],
       SelectionMove[cell, Cell, All, AutoScroll -> False];
       NotebookWrite[
         InputNotebook[], 
         ReplaceRepeated[celldata, pattern], AutoScroll -> False
       ];
     ]
   ];
   ,
   {cell, Cells[InputNotebook[], CellStyle -> "Input"]}
   ];
   MessageDialog["Done"];

]]
```

---

It may happen that it will miss an example from time to time, it should be rare though. In heavily edited notebook I have faced box structures that were not "proper" but good enough for FrontEnd to understand. So it may happen this "proper" pattern won't catch them.

Comment: I tried it on `ref/Part` and it works.

Comment: Tried it on a 700 pages notebook, and, although it seems to work, the end message doesn't appear. When I have a little time, I will try to trace if it is the notebook size or some specific code content.

Comment: @P.Fonseca it may be that's the size :)